# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - :delay in seconds for Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have the following native query:

```
... lockTimestamp + :delay SECOND) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

That I want to translate to Spring Data Jpa. The thing is that I get an error if I use it like this. I'm wondering if there is a direct translation to Spring Data Jpa or if not, I need to use something like this:

```
... lockTimestamp < :limitDate
```

Where limitDate is another Param in the Query calculated like:
DateUtils.addSeconds(new Date(), -delay)

Comment: try to clear your question again

Comment: Hi Eklavya, what do you mean?